# Crontab not working for mac

Tags: macos, cron

I am new to crontab and I have two questions, one is an example that I think should be working... and the other is a format question

I execute the following:

```
EDITOR=emacs crontab -e
```

And I put in

```
*       *       *       *       *       *       say test
```

When I quit out it says

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

But I don't hear the test voice coming every minute like it should.

I used this [site](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) as a reference for the format.  And I notice they use six fields.  However I've inherited a crontab at work that only uses 5.  Can you leave out the last?  How does the cron know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless OSX is doing something wonky, crontabs only have **5** time fields, and you've got 6. it's

```
minute hour day_of_month month day_of_week
```

So, most likely your crontab is trying to execute a script named `*`, with `say test` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  One thing I wanted to add (just for anyone who might be curious) is that you must add a newline after each command or it is not picked up